# large-scale server time solution

Tags: date, datetime, server, gmt

I am making a website for a large client, very simple, all self contained but they would like a timestamp for date-logic variations. Here's the catch, they want an 'absolute' time, aka if the user changes their pc clock it will still return the correct time.

the resource I've found for this is http://json-time.appspot.com, however there doesn't appear to be any documentation on the license nor limitations of accessing this. As this project will likely be getting 10000+ hits daily (for about 3 days)I now need to be certain it will return.

does anybody know of a server-clock that I can reference? pay-for or free, just needs to be reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard protocol for clock synchronisation is [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).  There are a number of freely usable, accurate NTP servers on the Internet, notably within the [NTP pool](http://www.pool.ntp.org/).

There are also a number of NTP client implementations available, but most are designed to set the system time.  For Unix/Linux, I can recommend:

- the [NTP reference implementation](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/ntpd.html);
- [Chrony](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/).

Do not use OpenNTPd, which is buggy.

If you do not have root access on your server, you'll probably be unable to run any of the above, which want to set the system time.  In that case, you can implement client NTP functionality within your application — the (S)NTP protocol is fairly simple, [well documented](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4330), and can be implemented in a couple of hours if you're familiar with sockets programming.